# Rename table to hide content from wordpress admin

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, hide, backend

we have some sensitive data in our wordpress backend and need to hire a freelancer to fix some things, unrelated to this feature containing the data to be hidden.

As this feature has been hardcoded by the old coder (not a plugin) we want to play safe with the hiding process.

My idea was to put simply an unused table prefix to the table that contains the data, so it won't be displayed in the wordpress backend. After the coder has done his job, we just would remove the suffix.

Do you think it would work like that and makes any sense?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Dump the table and remove it. later you can import the table again

Comment: Renaming the table would only hide it from the most basic prying eyes. Bernd's recommendation is the only way to be sure.

Comment: Thank you guys - I just had the experience a few times, that PHPmyAdmin comes with problems, once bigger tables are rolled back.
As the coder will have only WP access but no FTP and MySql Access I thought it would be the most quick and efficient way, without risking anything.